# How can I parse a block of html for three seperate items using xslt 1.0?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the below input XML:

```
<CALL>
<Message>&lt;meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"&gt;
    &lt;style&gt;p { margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica,
    sans-serif;font-size:13px;}&lt;/style&gt; &lt;span&gt; &lt;span&gt; &lt;span&gt;
    &lt;span&gt; &lt;span&gt; &lt;span&gt; &lt;span&gt; &lt;span&gt; &lt;span&gt; &lt;span&gt;
    &lt;span&gt; &lt;font face="Times New Roman" size="3"&gt; &lt;/font&gt; &lt;p style="margin:
    0cm 0cm 0pt;"&gt; &lt;font color="#1f4e79" face="Calibri" size="3"
    &gt;ID=&lt;/font&gt; &lt;b&gt; &lt;span style="background: white; color: black;
    font-family: &amp;quot;Arial&amp;quot;,sans-serif; font-size: 9pt;" &gt;
    996712804&lt;/span&gt; &lt;/b&gt; &lt;/p&gt; &lt;font face="Times New Roman" size="3"&gt;
    &lt;/font&gt; &lt;p style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt;"&gt; &lt;span style="color: rgb(31, 73,
    125);"&gt; &lt;font face="Calibri" size="3" &gt;Name= 05&lt;/font&gt;
    &lt;/span&gt; &lt;/p&gt; &lt;font face="Times New Roman" size="3"&gt; &lt;/font&gt; &lt;p
    style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt;"&gt; &lt;font face="Calibri"&gt; &lt;font size="3"&gt; &lt;font
    color="#1f4e79"&gt;Remarks=&lt;/font&gt; &lt;span style="color: rgb(31, 73, 125);"&gt;
    Accepted&lt;/span&gt; &lt;/font&gt; &lt;/font&gt; &lt;/p&gt; &lt;font face="Times New
    Roman"&gt; &lt;/font&gt; &lt;/span&gt; &lt;/span&gt; &lt;/span&gt; &lt;/span&gt;
    &lt;/span&gt; &lt;/span&gt; &lt;/span&gt; &lt;/span&gt; &lt;/span&gt; &lt;/span&gt;
    &lt;/span&gt; &lt;br/&gt; &lt;/meta&gt; </Message>
```

In it there are three items; ID, Name, and Remarks which I am trying to get to look like this:

```
<ID>996712804</ID>
<Name>05</Name>
<Remarks>Accepted</Remarks>
```

But I'm not sure how I can parse out the html tags and then separately parse the three tags that I need.

Would I have to parse out the html and in the same variable do a substring-after? Any clues are appreciated!

Comment: So which XSLT 1.0 processor on which platform exactly do you use? Will that block always be escaped, well-formed XHTML? Can your XSLT 1 processor call extension functions to parse XML or HTML? Are you sure you can't move to XSLT 3 where such stuff can be solved with on-board means, like I tried in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2CA?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for taking a look! That block will always be escaped and I'm currently just using Oxygen to test this out with and unfortunately has to be done in 1.0.

Comment: Which is the target XSLT 1.0 processor? I only see a way to implement that easily and robustly in XSLT 1 if the processor allows to call into extensions provided by the programming language/platform to parse that escaped markup into a tree and then to apply XSLT/XPath on it.